# How to deactivate or cease script execution from a specific directory

Tags: python, flask

I have a directory having user uploaded scripts, Python, Js and so on, but due to the fear of security breach I want to deactivate those script in such directory to restrict them from execution.

I wanna use python flask to do so (Python 3).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you would like to allow the user to upload arbitrary files to your sever. A good idea here would be create a secure file name before saving it in the server. The official documentation suggests using `secure_filename` to achieve this, however also notes that you may need to disallow certain extension if the server executes the file ('php' for example).

(Assuming you are using SQLAlchemy)

You can create a model that will store the custom filename and meta data about the file. Below is a sample app using some of the code from the [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/).

```
from flask import (Flask, request,
    send_from_directory, abort, redirect)
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from uuid import uuid4
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'change'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './uploads'
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1000 * 1000

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uploaded_files = db.relationship('UserFile', backref='user')

class UserFile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(50))
    client_filename = db.Column(db.String(100))
    ... #other file info
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            filename = f"{str(uuid4())}.txt"
            db.session.add(UserFile(
                filename=filename,
                client_filename = secure_filename(file.filename) #minimize security issues in the future
                #user_id = however you determine who the user is
            ))
            db.session.commit()
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/files/<int:id_>/download')
def file_download(id_):
    user_file = UserFile.query.get(id_)
    if not user_file:
        abort(404)
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], user_file.filename, 
        attachment_filename = user_file.client_filename,
        as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```